# Comparing objects in ruby

Tags: ruby, object, compare

Consider this:

```
class Aaa
  attr_accessor :a, :b
end

x = Aaa.new
x.a, x.b = 1,2
y = Aaa.new
y.a, y.b = 1,2

puts x == y #=>false
```

Is there some way to check if all public attributes are equal in classes of same type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Ruby method for determining if all instance variables of two instances of the same class are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844150/is-there-a-ruby-method-for-determining-if-all-instance-variables-of-two-instance)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class Aaa
  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def ==(other)
    return self.a == other.a && self.b == other.b
  end
end

x = Aaa.new
x.a,x.b = 1,2
y = Aaa.new
y.a,y.b = 1,2
y = Aaa.new
y.a,y.b = 1,2
z = Aaa.new
z.a,z.b = 1,3

x == y # => true
x == z # => false
```

Comment: But what if i want to do this using other classes? Or if there are 100 attributes?

Comment: In your ==(other) method, you could do self.instance_variables.each do |ivar| self.ivar == other.ivar end

You may want to look at === as well.

Comment: Using `Struct` or `OpenStruct` has these sorts of cases built into them.

Answer (score 9):

```
Aaa = Struct.new(:a, :b)

x = Aaa.new
x.a, x.b = 1,2
y = Aaa.new
y.a, y.b = 1,2

x == y #=> true
```

`Struct` defines `==`, `eql?`, and `hash` for you, so that two `Aaa`s are equal, if their values for `a` and `b` are equal. It also defines `initialize` so that you can optionally pass in the values for `a` and `b` when creating the object (`Aaa.new(value_for_a, value_for_b)`). And it defines `to_a` to return `[a,b]`.

You can also use `Struct.new` with a block to define additional methods, so you have the full power of a "normal" class:

```
Aaa = Struct.new(:a, :b) do
  def c
    a+b
  end
end
Aaa.new(23,42).c #=> 65
```

Comment: This seems fine but I need this functionality for objects, anyway nice response I didn't know about Structs

Comment: @dfens: Those are objects. `Struct.new` is just a factory method for classes. You'd get the exact same behavior if you'd define `Aaa` using the `class` keyword and then defined `==` etc. yourself.

Answer (score 2):

We can easily generalize to any number of instances and drop the requirement for getters for the instance variables:

```
class Aaa
  def initialize(a,b,c)
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
  end
end

x = Aaa.new(1,2,3)
y = Aaa.new(1,2,3)
z = Aaa.new(1,2,3)
arr = [x,y,z]

x.instance_variables.map do |v|
  arr.map { |i| i.send(:instance_variable_get,v) }.uniq.size == 1
end.all?
  #=>true
```

Change `z` to:

```
z = Aaa.new(1,2,4)
```

then:

```
x.instance_variables.map do |v|
  arr.map { |i| i.send(:instance_variable_get,v) }.uniq.size == 1
end.all?
  #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra method to deal with comparing objects in Ruby consists in using `hash`. For performance reason, when the class are huge, the best is to use `hash` to compare ruby objects as so :

```
class Aaa
  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def intialize(value_a,value_b)
     @a = value_a
     @b = value_b
  end 

  def hash(target)
     @a.hash == target.a.hash  && @b.hash == target.b.hash 
  end
end

A = new Aaa('whatever','whenever')
B = new Aaa('however','whoever')
A.hash(B)
```

Comment: This won't work as expected. Two different unequal objects can have the same hash value and the same object may not have the same hash value between invocations of Ruby. Furthermore, #hash is supposed to return an integer, not a boolean. This is only useful to do a quick check to see if two values *might* be equal, and for bucketing keys in a Hash for quick lookup.

https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Object.html#method-i-hash