# Delete duplicate elements from Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays, `array1` and `array2`, as follows:

```
array1 = [ obj11, obj21, obj31 ]
array2 = [ obj21, obj22, obj23 ]
```

Objects in both arrays are from the same class. I want to check if `array1` contains objects that already exist in `array2` and delete them.

Let's say `obj11` and `obj22` are equal. By "equal," I mean they have similar attribute values. Then I would like to delete `obj11` from `array1`, then insert `obj21` and `obj31` in `array2`.

I already define equality for attributes in the objects' class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941074/comparing-objects-in-ruby):

```
def ==(other)
  return self.a == other.a && self.b == other.b
end
```

The resulting array would be:

```
array2 = [ obj21, obj22, obj23, obj21, obj31 ]
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Show us an example of what your resulting array will be.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#|` ( it does union operation) to remove duplicates too.

```
array1 = ["dog", "cat", "had"]
array2 = ["big", "fight", "had"]
array1 | array2
# => ["dog", "cat", "had", "big", "fight"]
```

Comment: @Arwa I was following your subject line *Delete object from array if already exist*.. If you are dealing with `Array`, not need to define your own.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to remove duplicate values from multiple arrays is by using `uniq`

```
array1 = ["dog", "cat", "had"]
array2 = ["big", "fight", "had"]

new_array = (array1 + array2).uniq  # <- ["dog", "cat", "had", "big", "fight"]
```

`uniq` removes duplicate values from an array. By combining `array1` and `array2` together, you can then filter out duplicates between the two of them.

Answer (score 1):

If I want to solve your problem literally, then, I will write something like this:

```
array1 = [ :obj11, :obj21, :obj31 ]
array2 = [ :obj21, :obj22, :obj23 ]

new_array = (array1 - array2) + array2
p new_array
```

`(array1 - array2)` takes those elements from `array1` that are also present in `array2` and adding `array2` to that will get you the final result

*Output*

```
[:obj11, :obj31, :obj21, :obj22, :obj23]
```

---

*(Note: I used symbols as elements of arrays for illustration purposes)*

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. In the following I delete from array1 what is already exist in array2. Equality here works as I define it in the question. Thus, checking if attributes (that have been defined in the method ==) are equal.

```
array1.delete_if{|elem| array2.any?{|e| e == elem}}
```

Then add the rest of array1 into array2.

```
array2 << array1
```

Then I flatten array2.

```
array2.flatten!
```

Comment: Good answer. Rather than `array2 << array1; array2.flatten!` I would suggest `array2.concat(array1)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that as follows:

```
 a2.concat(a1.delete_if { |e| a2.include?(e) })
```

Here's an example:

```
class MyClass
  attr_reader :a, :b, :c
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
  end
  def ==(other)
    self.a == other.a && self.b == other.b
  end
end

a1 = [MyClass.new('cat', 'bat', 'rat'),
      MyClass.new('dog', 'hog', 'pig'),
      MyClass.new('jay', 'bee', 'fly'),]
  #=> [#<MyClass:0x007fca8407b678 @a="cat", @b="bat", @c="rat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007fca8407bee8 @a="dog", @b="hog", @c="pig">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007fca84073ef0 @a="jay", @b="bee", @c="fly">] 
a2 = [MyClass.new('fly', 'bee', 'bat'),
      MyClass.new('cat', 'bat', 'rat'),
      MyClass.new('dog', 'hog', 'cat'),] 
  #=> [#<MyClass:0x007fca840382d8 @a="fly", @b="bee", @c="bat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007fca840381e8 @a="cat", @b="bat", @c="rat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007fca840380d0 @a="dog", @b="hog", @c="cat">] 

a2.concat(a1.delete_if { |e| a2.include?(e) })
  #=> [#<MyClass:0x007f96d404ea08 @a="fly", @b="bee", @c="bat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007f96d404e8c8 @a="cat", @b="bat", @c="rat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007f96d404e710 @a="dog", @b="hog", @c="cat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007f96d409d9c8 @a="jay", @b="bee", @c="fly">] 
a1
  #=> [#<MyClass:0x007f96d409d9c8 @a="jay", @b="bee", @c="fly">]
```

If we change the first element of `a1` from:

```
 MyClass.new('cat', 'bat', 'rat')
```

to:

```
 MyClass.new('cat', 'rat', 'bat')
```

we obtain:

```
a2.concat(a1.delete_if { |e| a2.include?(e) })
  #=> [#<MyClass:0x007f89528568c0 @a="fly", @b="bee", @c="bat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007f8952856708 @a="cat", @b="bat", @c="rat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007f89528562d0 @a="dog", @b="hog", @c="cat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007f89519277f0 @a="cat", @b="rat", @c="bat">,
  #    #<MyClass:0x007f8951927598 @a="jay", @b="bee", @c="fly">]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (using `intersection` operation):

```
   array1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
   array2 = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
   final_array = array1 + array2
   final_array & final_array
```

This will also delete duplicates. IRB output:

```
2.2.1 :012 > array1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
2.2.1 :013 > array2 = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
 => [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
2.2.1 :014 > final_array = array1 + array2
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
2.2.1 :015 > final_array & final_array
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```