# Is there a Ruby method for determining if all instance variables of two instances of the same class are equal?

Tags: ruby

Is there a Ruby method for comparing two objects based on whether all of their instance variables are equal? The method would behave like this code.

```
class Coordinates
  attr_reader :x, :y
  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
end

coordinates1 = Coordinates.new(0, 0)
coordinates2 = Coordinates.new(0, 0)
coordinates3 = Coordinates.new(1, 0)

compare(coordinates1, coordinates1) # => true
compare(coordinates1, coordinates2) # => true
compare(coordinates1, coordinates3) # => false
```

Does this method or something similar exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1**

```
class A
  def initialize(x,y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
  def m
    @x = 5
    @y = 6
  end
end
```

```
a1 = A.new(1,2)
   #=> #<A:0x00005d22a3878048 @x=1, @y=2> 
a1.m
a1 #=> #<A:0x00005d22a3878048 @x=5, @y=6>
```

```
a2 = A.new(3,4)
   #=> #<A:0x00005d22a38b5330 @x=3, @y=4> 
a2.m
a2 #=> #<A:0x00005d22a38b5330 @x=5, @y=6>
```

Then,

```
a1.instance_variables.all? { |e|
  a1.instance_variable_get(e) == a2.instance_variable_get(e) }
  #=> true
```

tells us that the values of `@x` and the values of `@y` are the same for both instances.

**Case 2**

Now let's change the code so that another instance variable is added conditionally.

```
class A
  def initialize(x,y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
  def m
    @z = 3 if @x == 3
    @x = 5
    @y = 6
  end
end
```

```
a1 = A.new(1,2)
   #=> #<A:0x000057d1fd563c78 @x=1, @y=2> 
a1.m
a1 #=> #<A:0x000057d1fd27f200 @x=5, @y=6>
```

```
a2 = A.new(3,4)
   #=> #<A:0x000057d1fd57cb38 @x=3, @y=4>
a2.m
a2 #=> #<A:0x000057d1fd2f9e10 @x=5, @y=6, @z=3>
```

At this point are all instance variables of one of these instances equal to the corresponding instance variable of the other instance? No, because `a2` has an additional instance variable, `@z`. Therefore,

```
a1.instance_variables.all? { |e|
  a1.instance_variable_get(e) == a2.instance_variable_get(e) }
  #=> true
```

gives the wrong answer, for obvious reasons. Perhaps we could test as follows:

```
a1.instance_variables.all? { |e|
  a1.instance_variable_get(e) == a2.instance_variable_get(e) } &&
a2.instance_variables.all? { |e|
  a1.instance_variable_get(e) == a2.instance_variable_get(e) } 
 #=> true && false => false
```

This has a gotcha, however, if `@z` equals `nil`.

**Case 3**

```
class A
  def initialize(x,y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
  def m
    @z = nil if @x == 3
    @x = 5
    @y = 6
  end
end

a1 = A.new(1,2)
   #=> #<A:0x000057d1fd2d18e8 @x=1, @y=2> 
a1.m
a1 #=> #<A:0x000057d1fd2d18e8 @x=5, @y=6>
```

```
a2 = A.new(3,4)
  #=> #<A:0x000057d1fd46b460 @x=3, @y=4> 
a2.m
a2
  #=> #<A:0x000057d1fd46b460 @x=5, @y=6, @z=nil>
```

```
a1.instance_variables.all? { |e|
  a1.instance_variable_get(e) == a2.instance_variable_get(e) } &&
a2.instance_variables.all? { |e|
  a1.instance_variable_get(e) == a2.instance_variable_get(e) }
  #=> true && true => true
```

We obtain this incorrect result because:

```
class A
end

A.new.instance_variable_get(:@z)
  #=> nil
```

We therefore must confirm that if one instance has an instance variable named `e`, so does the other instance, and that each pair of instance variables with the same name are equal. One way to do that is as follows:

```
(a1.instance_variables.sort == a2.instance_variables.sort) &&
a1.instance_variables.all? { |e|
  a1.instance_variable_get(e) == a2.instance_variable_get(e) }    
  #=> false && true => false
```

See [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F), [Object#instance_variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables) and [Object#instance_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get).

Comment: If the instance variables have different names (e.g. If we're comparing two completely different classes) then is this method expected to return true or false? *shrug*

Comment: @Tom, doesn't the question's title and example make it cIear that the two instances being compared are from the same class?

Comment: I suppose so... But there's nothing in your method that assures this ;)

Comment: @Tom, can you elaborate? I thought it was straightforward. Are you looking to raise an exception within the method if `a1.class != a2.class`?

Comment: My point was that the requirements of the method are quite fuzzy (and it was almost certainly an XY question, I think!) -- there are a myriad of ways that the method *could* work. For example, is it invalid if you compare a class with a subclass? What happens if two instances of the same class have different instance variables? (Instance variables may be set dynamically in a method, not the initialiser!) "Having the same instance variables" is a very fuzzy/ill-defined check for equality, so there's no concrete answer to the problem.

Answer (score 7):

There is no built-in method for this, but you could quite easily write one. However, I think you're asking an XY question.

Here is what I think the question is supposed to say:

> How should I define a method to check that two `Coordinates` instances are equal?

And here's my answer:

Define a custom `==` method:

```
class Coordinates
  attr_reader :x, :y
  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  def ==(other)
    return super unless other.is_a?(Coordinates)

    x == other.x && y == other.y
  end
end
```

---

...But in the spirit of StackOverflow, here's some meta-programming to check whether all instance variables have the same name and value:

```
# returns true if all objects have the same instance variable names and values
def compare(*objects)
  objects.map do |object|
    object.instance_variables.map do |var_name|
      [var_name, object.instance_variable_get(var_name)]
    end
  end.uniq.count == 1
end
```

Comment: I think you should be overriding the `===` method, and not `==`. See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-3D-3D

Comment: @ReggieB I disagree. It is perfectly fine to override `==` in cases like this. From the documentation you linked, it says: *"Typically, this method is overridden in descendant classes to provide class-specific meaning."*